How can I define a custom coordinate system and ensure that other views maintain their positions relative to it?
I have a black color, let's say a black screen, and I want to make this black screen the base coordinate system for my app—not the GeometryReader, but the black screen itself. I created the code below to test if the black screen is being used as the true coordinate system. I want the top-left corner of the black screen to be the origin, and for it to work like SwiftUI's Path coordinate system, where the axes are consistent.
However, my code has some issues. First, when I move my circle to the top-left corner of the black screen, I don't get (0, 0) as the CGPoint, which suggests the custom coordinate system isn't working as expected. Second, when I place my circle on the screen, I want it to maintain its position relative to the top and left sides of the black screen, even if I resize the window. Currently, the circle's position changes when I resize the window.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let circleSize: CGFloat = 50.0
    let randomValue = CGFloat.random(in: 50.0...100.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryValue in
            ZStack {
                
                Color.black
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "BlackScreen")
                
                CircleView(circleSize: circleSize) { newValue in

                    let localPoint = CGPoint(
                        x: newValue.x + geometryValue.frame(in: .named("BlackScreen")).width/2.0 - circleSize/2.0,
                        y: newValue.y + geometryValue.frame(in: .named("BlackScreen")).height/2.0 - circleSize/2.0
                    )
                    print(localPoint)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(randomValue)
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    
    let circleSize: CGFloat
    var point: (CGPoint) -> Void
    
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var currentOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
            .overlay(Circle().fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5)).frame(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
            .offset(currentOffset)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named("BlackScreen"))
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                currentOffset = CGSize(
                    width: gestureValue.translation.width + lastOffset.width,
                    height: gestureValue.translation.height + lastOffset.height
                )
                
                point(gestureValue.location)
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                lastOffset = currentOffset
            }
    }
}


First issue:
Let's say our tolerance with hand and mouse is 1.0. As you can see, almost zero-zero has a significant difference when being used as the base coordinate system.



issue:




I do get something close to (0, 0) when the circle is around the top left corner.

Please look at new photo in question.

The first problem is because CircleView is returning the location of the mouse pointer. That is what gestureValue.location means. It is not the location of the center of the circle.
The second problem is because the ZStack is using .center alignment. The center of the ZStack moves as you resize the window, but the circle's offset does not change, so the circle moves as well.
Both of these problems can be solved, if you just align the circle in such a way that a currentOffset of .zero means the center of the circle is at the top left.
First, use .topLeading as the ZStack alignment. The "top leading" point of the ZStack never changes as you resize the window.
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    Color.black
    CircleView(circleSize: circleSize) {
        print($0)
    }
}
.padding(randomValue)

Then in CircleView you can use alignmentGuide to make the center of the circle to be the alignment guides for .top and .leading.
var body: some View {
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
        .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
        .overlay(Circle().fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5)).frame(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
        .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center] }
        .alignmentGuide(.leading) { $0[HorizontalAlignment.center] }
        .offset(currentOffset)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
}

Finally, convert currentOffset to a CGPoint before passing it to point.
private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named("BlackScreen"))
        .onChanged { gestureValue in
            currentOffset = CGSize(
                width: gestureValue.translation.width + lastOffset.width,
                height: gestureValue.translation.height + lastOffset.height
            )
            
            point(CGPoint(x: currentOffset.width, y: currentOffset.height))
        }
        .onEnded { gestureValue in
            lastOffset = currentOffset
        }
}

There is no need for coordinateSpaces and GeometryReaders, because Color.black fills the whole ZStack.

I really do not want to use alignment; I would like to handle it mathematically. Also, in the ZStack, I need the circle to be centered initially. Changing the ZStack alignment causes design issues with my other views that I am using in the ZStack. that is why I used: 'newValue.x + geometryValue.frame(in: .named("BlackScreen")).width/2.0 - circleSize/2.0 ...'

@swiftPunk You can center the circle initially by just setting currentOffset to the coordinate you want in onAppear.

@swiftPunk If you don't want to change the alignment of the ZStack, how about Color.black.overlay(alignment: .topLeading) { CircleView() }?

From ContentView? I do not want set value of currentOffset in child view, I want keep it internal

Same as ZStack, I cannot change any alignment on Black Screen as well.

Exactly, I was going to do that, but the issue with testing the BlackScreen coordinate system stopped me from taking further steps because I was processing the wrong data.

No need to update, I am going to answer my question. let keep both ways here as answers.

@swiftPunk Actually I was just about to edit. I'll see what you came up with and if it is different from mine, I'll post my updated approach tomorrow.

I really liked your approch in mater of fact you just answered the question with given condition, you done your part perfectly, it is my app situation that is not compatible with your approach.

By the way I interested to your new approach, would you add it if you made it to the tail of this answer?

You said I can center the circle by setting currentOffset with onAppear, so then we need GeometryReader to read the size of BlackScreen and pass it down to circle view, right?

@swiftPunk yes. In that case you do need a geometry reader.

Instead of calling point in onChange of the gesture, put a  GeometryReader in CircleView to observe changes in the circle's frame. Pass the center of that frame to point.
CircleView can store its position as an x-y coordinate from the top left of the black screen. By observing changes in the circle's frame when the user is not dragging, it can determine how it should adjust the currentOffset so that it maintains the same position relative to the top left.
struct CircleView: View {
    
    let circleSize: CGFloat
    var point: (CGPoint) -> Void
    
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var currentOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var position: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
            .overlay {
                Circle().fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5)).frame(width: 4.0, height: 4.0)
            }
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    let frameInBlackScreen = geo.frame(in: .named("BlackScreen"))
                    Color.clear
                        .onChange(of: frameInBlackScreen) { _, frame in
                            if isDragging {
                                position = .init(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
                                point(.init(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY))
                            } else {
                                // the window is resized, the circle is moved to 'newPosition'
                                let oldPosition = position
                                let newPosition = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
                                currentOffset.width -= newPosition.x - oldPosition.x
                                currentOffset.height -= newPosition.y - oldPosition.y
                            }
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            // get the initial position
                            let frameInBlackScreen = geo.frame(in: .named("BlackScreen"))
                            position = .init(x: frameInBlackScreen.midX, y: frameInBlackScreen.midY)
                        }
                }
            }
            .offset(currentOffset)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    @GestureState private var isDragging = false
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named("BlackScreen"))
            .updating($isDragging) { _, state, _ in state = true }
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                currentOffset = CGSize(
                    width: gestureValue.translation.width + lastOffset.width,
                    height: gestureValue.translation.height + lastOffset.height
                )
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                lastOffset = currentOffset
            }
    }
}

Note that the geometry reader in CircleView cannot access the "BlackScreen" coordinate space, because Color.black is a sibling of CircleView. The coordinateSpace modifier must be a parent of CircleView. ContentView should be set up like this:
ZStack {
    Color.black
    CircleView(circleSize: circleSize) { print($0) }
}
.coordinateSpace(name: "BlackScreen")

or
Color.black
    .overlay {
        CircleView(circleSize: circleSize) { print($0) }
    }
    .coordinateSpace(name: "BlackScreen")


The answer provided by Sweeper is the correct way to address the issue. However, due to my app's requirements, I had to take a different approach to solve the issue. Here's my solution, but again, the most logical approach is the accepted answer.(iOS 15.0, macOS: 12.0)
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentContainerSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastContainerSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    @State private var circlePosition: CGPoint = .zero
    
    @State private var communicationPoint: CommunicationPointType = CommunicationPointType()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryValue in
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                CircleView(communicationPoint: communicationPoint) { newValue in
                    
                    circlePosition = CGPoint(x: newValue.width + geometryValue.size.width/2.0 + offset.width,
                                             y: newValue.height + geometryValue.size.height/2.0 + offset.height)
                    
                    print(circlePosition)
                }
                .offset(offset)
                
            }
            .onChange(of: geometryValue.size) { newValue in
                if (lastContainerSize != .zero) {
                    currentContainerSize = newValue
                    
                    offset = CGSize(
                        width: offset.width - (newValue.width - lastContainerSize.width)/2.0,
                        height: offset.height - (newValue.height - lastContainerSize.height)/2.0
                    )
                    
                    lastContainerSize = newValue
                }
                else {
                    currentContainerSize = newValue
                    lastContainerSize = newValue
                }
                
            }
        }
        .padding(100.0)
        
        HStack {
            Button("topLeading") {
                communicationPoint = CommunicationPointType(width: -currentContainerSize.width/2.0, height: -currentContainerSize.height/2.0)
                offset = .zero
            }
            
            Button("center") {
                communicationPoint = CommunicationPointType(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
                offset = .zero
            }
        }
        .padding()
 
    }
}




struct CircleView: View {
    
    let communicationPoint: CommunicationPointType
    var circleOffset: (CGSize) -> Void
    
    let circleSize: CGFloat = 50.0
    
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var currentOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
            .overlay(Circle().fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5)).frame(width: 4.0, height: 4.0))
            .offset(currentOffset)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
            .onChange(of: communicationPoint) { newValue in
                
                if (newValue.id != communicationPoint.id) {
                    currentOffset = newValue.size
                    lastOffset = newValue.size
                    circleOffset(newValue.size)
                }
                
            }
        
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged { gestureValue in
                currentOffset = CGSize(
                    width: gestureValue.translation.width + lastOffset.width,
                    height: gestureValue.translation.height + lastOffset.height
                )
                circleOffset(currentOffset)
            }
            .onEnded { gestureValue in
                lastOffset = currentOffset
                circleOffset(currentOffset)
            }
    }
}


struct CommunicationPointType: Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    init(size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
    }
    
    init() {
        self.size = CGSize()
    }
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var size: CGSize
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.id == rhs.id) && (lhs.size == rhs.size)
    }
    
}

